# Why aren't empty arrays and hashes interned?

Tags: arrays, ruby, optimization, language-lawyer

Recently I found out that Ruby doesn't optimize `[]` and `{}` to be interned to point to a common shared object. Demo:

```rb
irb(main):001:0> [].object_id
=> 70284401361960
irb(main):002:0> [].object_id
=> 70284392762340 # different
irb(main):003:0> [].object_id
=> 70284124310100 # different

irb(main):005:0> {}.object_id
=> 70284392857480
irb(main):006:0> {}.object_id
=> 70284392870480 # different
irb(main):007:0> {}.object_id
=> 70284392904360 # different
```

I understand that often empty hashes and array literals are used to initialize values that will be immediately mutated. But this *happens even if you freeze them* with `[].freeze.object_id` or `{}.freeze.object_id` instead.

Contrast this with `String`, when the env var `RUBYOPT` is set to `--enable-frozen-string-literal`:

```rb
irb(main):001:0> ""
=> 70284400947400
irb(main):002:0> ""
=> 70284400947400 # same
irb(main):003:0> ""
=> 70284400947400 # same
```

Even you don't enable frozen string literals, if you call `"".freeze.object_id` instead, you'll get the same object id each time, though I suspect that initial `""` literal is still allocated an intermediate string object that `freeze` is being called on.

In a performance-sensitive codebase (well, as performance-sensitive you can allow yourself to be while still using MRI lol) I've seen this workaround, which uses the following shared constants instead of `[]` or `{}` for cases when the hash or array doesn't need to be mutable:

```rb
module LessAllocations
  EMPTY_HASH = {}.freeze
  EMPTY_ARRAY = [].freeze

  # String literals are already frozen, use '' instead
  # EMPTY_STRING = ''
end
```

So my questions are:

1. Is this a missed optimization opportunity?

   It seems like a peephole optimization could be written to intern frozen empty hash or array literals. Would need to be part of the language's semantics, i.e. would there be any observable differences, (obviously besides the behavior of `object_id`)?
2. Are empty hash and array literals represented by tagged pointers? Do they even cause any allocation to happen?

Comment: If `[]` was always the same object could you imagine all the horrible side effects? Unless you are suggesting that `Array` literals should be immutable, which has a whole different set of drawbacks. `Hash` would suffer from the same and more concerns.

Comment: @engineersmnky "I understand that often empty hashes and array literals are used to initialize values that will be immediately mutated. But this happens even if you do [].freeze.object_id or {}.freeze.object_id instead."

Comment: The size of `[]` and `{}` is actually about 8 bytes in practice. They're super cheap already. The savings here would be negligible unless you're dealing with billions of them.

Comment: @tadman It's not just the total memory size, but also the GC bookkeeping overhead. Consider also that you can't malloc a block smaller than a particular system-defined size. Allocating just 0 or 1 bytes yields a 16 byte allocation (on macOS on my 64 bit Intel mac). It also appears to be [more than 8 bytes](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/48b94b791997881929c739c64f95ac30f3fd0bb9/include/ruby/internal/core/rarray.h#L87-L105), in the first place. By my count, it's 5 words, 40 bytes, with a min allocation of 48 bytes on my system

Comment: You'll need to do some tests and show how fixing this could actually impact performance, and if it does, then work towards a solution that doesn't break anything. From a GC perspective an empty array is cheap to track, it's not complicated and it's easy to deal with. Large, self-referential structures are where GC gets expensive.

Comment: @tadman I don't really have access to an application that would be a good performance benchmark for this. But I would be very highly surprised if this wasn't one of the considerations (after all, it was a concern for `String`.)

Comment: The reasoning behind string, you'll note, is not empty strings per-se, but duplicate strings. Every instance of `"example"` can now be the same object. Every empty array is as close to zero cost as you can get already.

Comment: @tadman Good point. Though even just empty hashes/arrays would be quite popular. Think of keyword args or var args methods where none were provided, or DSLs that make heavy use of hashes for more complex behavior, but are often left empty.

Comment: True, but I think you'll find in practice that an empty hash or array is treated as basically an "empty" pointer. A lot of Ruby objects are just 8 byte values (on 64-bit) unless they need additional data. There's a big difference in size between a one-entry hash or array and a zero-entry one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a missed optimization opportunity?

To answer this question one would to have to do a survey of real world memory usage, but I believe it is unlikely. You could perform a little experiment...

```
class Array
  EMPTY_ARRAY = [].freeze
  
  def freeze
    empty? ? EMPTY_ARRAY : super
  end
end
```

Empty objects are very small. Having so many that they use significant memory compared to everything else your program is using memory for is an edge case.

> I understand that often empty hashes and array literals are used to initialize values that will be immediately mutated.

For that reason, adding copy-on-write to empty hashes and arrays might slow things down.

> But this happens even if you do [].freeze.object_id or
> {}.freeze.object_id instead.

Freezing them means you know ahead of time they will remain empty, that's extremely rare. Having so many known empty hashes and arrays that it becomes a performance issue is an edge case. The constant work-around seems fine.

Comment: Perhaps `empty? ? EMPTY_ARRAY  : super`?